ROS 2 send_action_goal Operation not Recognized
Description
After installing rosbridge_server with apt-get, I try to run the example of action client in ROS 2 from roslibjs. The ros client is connected but then when the example code tries to send the action request, the following message appears on the rosbridge-server terminal:
[rosbridge_websocket-1] [INFO] [1719650740.191282598] [rosbridge_websocket]: Calling services in existing thread
[rosbridge_websocket-1] [INFO] [1719650740.192217869] [rosbridge_websocket]: Client connected. 1 clients total.
[rosbridge_websocket-1] [ERROR] [1719650740.192975287] [rosbridge_websocket]: [Client b6ab93b5-4dd4-414e-9655-a7eb2581237d] [id: send_action_goal:/fibonacci:1] Unknown operation: send_action_goal.  Allowed operations: ['call_service', 'advertise', 'unadvertise', 'publish', 'subscribe', 'unsubscribe', 'fragment', 'advertise_service', 'service_response', 'unadvertise_service']

Given the list of allowed operations, it seems that the actions of the rosbridge protocol are not included. How can it be? I checked the Protocol documentation that explicitly talks about send_action_goal, so I am confused.
Library Version: 1.3.2-1jammy.20240530.094238 
ROS Version: Humble 
Platform / OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Steps To Reproduce

sudo apt-get install ros-humble-rosbridge-server

ros2 launch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket_launch.xml

git clone git@github.com:RobotWebTools/roslibjs.git

npm i

ros2 run action_tutorials_py fibonacci_action_server

open the HTML page at roslibjs/examples/ros2_action_client.html


